# Invoking __unicode__ method

Tags: python, django

New to python, and trying to use `__unicode_` to render a string representation. The code is part of Django model. How can I write `__unicode__` of MyType so that in templates it output its representation as `123 - 123 South ....`

```
class UsAddress(models.Model):
    #other fields
    zip = us_models.USPostalCodeField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    phone = us_models.PhoneNumberField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return  self.zip + self.country + self.phone


class MyType(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    address = UsAddress

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.code) + " - " + unicode(self.address) #self.address.__unicode__()
```

Output:

```
 <MyType: 219 - <class 'web.models.UsAddress'>>
```

### EDIT

At least in my case, the problem was I didn't model the relationship. So I added it to UsAddress.

```
mt = models.ForeignKey(MyType)
```

Comment: use `__str__` and/or `__repr__`   for printing ... use `__unicode__` for django (I think), and `unicode(MyClassInstance)`

Comment: A simple comment for @bsreekanth: `__unicode__` should return a `unicode` object, you're returning `basestring`. Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#unicode

Comment: To make your `__unicode__` method work, use `unicode(self.address)` instead of `self.address(unicode)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyType(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    address = UsAddress

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.code, self.address)
```

Here is the [unicode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#unicode) method.

Then, you can just use it in your template like this:

```
<p>My object: {{ mytype_obj }}</p>
```

The output will be:

> My object: 123 - 123 South ....